# How to register an Azure function to an API manager through ARM template?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm implementing an ARM template, which includes API manager, to automate my build prosess. However, I'm not sure how to register my azure function (these are being compiled via the build step in the pipline) to the created api manager via the arm template.

I have started with a simple arm template that included (among other things):
Microsoft.Web/serverfarms
Microsoft.Web/sites
which were later were used to deploy a precompiled azure functions (from devop git), via azure app service deploy step.

Then I tried to add an API manger to the mix by adding:
Microsoft.ApiManagement/service
Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis

However, now I can not figure out how to connect the api manager to include my azure functions.

This is the part where I add my api manager:

```
    {
      "name": "[variables('apiManagementName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service",
      "apiVersion": "2019-01-01",
      "tags": {},
      "properties": {
        "publisherEmail": "xxx",
        "publisherName": "xxx"
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "Consumption"
      },
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01-preview",
      "name": "[concat(variables('apiManagementName'), '/xxx-endpoint-dev')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', variables('apiManagementName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionAppName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "displayName": "xxx-Endpoint-dev",
        "apiRevision": "1",
        "description": "Import from \"xxx-Endpoint-dev\" Function App",
        "path": "xxx-Endpoint-dev",
        "protocols": [
          "https"
        ]
      }
    }
```

I have tried adding the "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/backends" s ection as described in the documentation, but couldn't make it work. I also had a look on this template : 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-api-management-create-all-resources 
but couldn't find my an answer in there either (might have missed it).

Is there any good example of how to do it? can it even be done via the ARM template?

Right now my template create all the resources and I can add the desired api via the portal (by adding api to my empty api manager), but I would like to automate this part as well.

to be more precise what I'm trying to understand is how to do this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-function-app-as-api
using ARM template.

Comment: What do you mean "couldn't make it work"? Please describe your issue with error messages.

Comment: Hey Sam, When trying to add the "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/backends"" section I add the parameter ""resourceId"" with the ID of my function (resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionAppName'))) but got the error that the parameter must be a URL. I also tried to add "serviceUrl" to the "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis" sector which result in the same error.

Comment: @LironLevy did you managed to make this work? I'm into a similar approach and having a hard time.

Comment: Hey @CastroRoy unfortantly this is not somthing that is possiable right now. I did solved it using a powershell script running in the pipeline.

see:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5fcdf93-53f3-4ad4-a9c0-4d7bdda37616/how-to-add-azure-functions-to-api-managment-via-arm-template?forum=azureapimgmt#2df21921-0732-4993-ae8b-5f1f018c0e7a

for the answer.

Comment: actually, I just found out that it is possible, but it is hard to write, see [this example](https://github.com/mspnp/serverless-reference-implementation/blob/master/src/azuredeploy-apim.json). The idea is to define `backends`, `apis` and `operations`, all belong to `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
As mentioned in the comments, it seems it is possible after all. See example [here](https://github.com/mspnp/serverless-reference-implementation/blob/master/src/azuredeploy-apim.json).

Old:
This is unfurtantly not completly fixable using ARM template, thus I had to add a powershell script to my pipeline. A answer detail can be found [here](https://memoryleek.wordpress.com/2018/11/20/setting-an-azure-function-host-key-at-deploy-time-with-azure-devops/) and [here](https://www.gsmulders.nl/2018/11/08/azure-how-to-add-a-host-key-to-your-azure-function-app-using-a-script/).

I came up with some kind of a in between method, getting the username and PWD from the ARM template. then running this script:

```
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$ARMOutput
)

# Convert the string into something a little more structured
$json = $ARMOutput | convertfrom-json

#Extract the values from our object 
$appName = $json.appName.value
$keyName = $json.keyName.value
$keyValue = $json.keyValue.value
$user = $json.userName.value
$pass = $json.userPWD.value

# Get Username and password for Kudu
$pair = "$($user):$($pass)"
$kuduCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))

# Get token from Kudu
$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://$appName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/functions/admin/token" -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $kuduCreds)} -Method GET

# Prepare call
$body = @{
  name  = $keyName
  value = $keyValue
} | ConvertTo-Json

$uri = "https://$appName.azurewebsites.net/admin/host/keys/$keyName"

# Call API
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Headers @{Authorization = ("Bearer {0}" -f $token); Accept = "application/json"} -ContentType "application/json" -Uri $uri -Body $body
```